# Reading specific rows based on date with fread

Tags: r, regex, fread

I am trying to read only specific rows from a large dataset based on a specific date using fread. The goal is to read the rows from 06/01/2018 to 06/02/2018 recorded in d/m/yyyy format.

```r
fread(paste("grep '^[1-2]/6/2018'", "filename"))
```

The expected output are all rows starting with 1/6/2018 and 2/6/2018 but I am also getting  11/6,12/6,21/6,22/6.
I have tried variations of regex ^[1,2], ^(1/6/2018 | 2/6/2018) etc, none produce the desired results.

Comment: Seems like R is giving you the date whenever the day has 1 or 2 inside of it, which is why you get 1,2,12,21,11,22. Can you try it this way ``fread(paste("grep '^[^1-2]/6/2018'", "filename"))`` please?

Comment: Try `fread(cmd=paste("grep","^[12]/6/2018","filename")`

Comment: @Gainz still getting the same results

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nope, still the same issue. The weird thing I tried the same exact syntax grep '^[1-2]/6/2018' with read.table and it works as it should but I cannot get it to work with fread

Comment: It is a windows system if that makes a difference

Comment: @jondoe For some functions and packages OS can change something but I don't think this is the case with fread().

Comment: So, does `fread(cmd=paste("grep","^0?[12]/0?6/2018","filename")` work?